# How to add a label to FieldListView in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity

I have a FieldListView that outputs the Last Modified date of the content (code at the bottom). How do I bind and display a static label (Last Modified as a pre-text) to this code in ASP.NET so it outputs the label inside the div like this:

```
<div>Last Modified: June 15, 2020</div>
```

Here's my code in Sitefinity:

```
<sf:FieldListView ID="LastModified" runat="server" Format="{LastModified.ToLocal():MMM dd, yyyy}" TextMode="Encode" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
<div>
    <sf:FieldListView ID="LastModified" runat="server" Format="Last Modified: {LastModified.ToLocal():MMM dd, yyyy}" TextMode="Encode" />
</div>
```